# firebase.auth() - Syntax error "unexpected token ."

Tags: javascript, firebase, syntax-error

I am trying to follow a video on youtube called "Full Stack React & Firebase Tutorial - Build a social media app" and I am having trouble with the code for adding new users to firebase..

My code looks like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('express')();

admin.initializeApp();

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "socialtutorial.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://socialtutorial.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "socialtutorial",
    storageBucket: "socialtutorial.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "SenderID",
    appId: "1:848457683801:web:a276f7436db03ac500b248"
}


const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

app.get('/challenges', (req, res) => {
    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('challenges')
        .orderBy('challengeCreated', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then(data => {
            let challenges = [];
            data.forEach(doc => {
            challenges.push({
                challengeId: doc.id,
                challengeName: doc.data().challengeName,
                challengeDescription: doc.data().challengeDescription,
                challengeCreated: doc.data().challengeCreated
            });
        });
        return res.json(challenges);
    })
    .catch (err => console.error(err));
})


app.post('/challenge', (req, res) => {

    const newChallenge = {
        challengeName: req.body.challengeName,
        challengeDescription: req.body.challengeDescription,
        challengeCreated: new Date().toISOString()

    };
    admin.firestore()
    .collection('challenges')
    .add(newChallenge)
    .then(doc => {
        res.json({message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully`});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'something went wrong'});
        console.error(err);
    })
 })

 //Sign Up Route

 app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
     const newUser = {
         email: req.body.email,
         password: req.body.password,
         confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
         userName: req.body.userName
     }

     //TODO Validate
     firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
        .then(data => {
            return res.status(201).json({message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully`});
        })
        .catch(err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: err.code})
        }
 })

 exports.api = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(app);
```

Now, when I try "firebase deploy" or "serve" I get an unexpected token error. The error is the "." after firebase... I must have missed something in the code above, but I can't see it for the life of me. I know this is a stupid mistake and I should be able to fix it on my own, but I literally can't see, where the error comes from...

Any help from you guys? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is the error message (in full) and what line of your code does it refer to, please?

Comment: `.catch(err) =>`  there's your problem. Move that `)` to after the `}`

Comment: FYI, my VSCode showed that up as a syntax error so perhaps use a better IDE

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if maybe you copied pasted to the question incorrectly from your editor but the only thing I see is the last `catch` of your code. It seems you never pass a callback to it.
you defined it as follows

```
.catch(err) => {
```

but it should be

```
.catch(err => {
```

Comment: This is embarrassing... thanks for the help mate... I didn't see that and spent an hour going over this code... Note to myself: Do not code at 6 in the morning...